# WinForms Validating event not fired?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, event-handling, textbox

I have multiple TextBoxes and whenever they lose focus / another box receives focus, I want their content to be validated. For example if I jump to the next textbox using tab or mouse.

Each of the textboxes has an event handler.

```
 this.textBox.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.textBox_Validating);
```

`textBox.CausesValidation` is true. So it should cause validation when it receives focus.

Yet none of the TextBoxes fires its validating event. The event handler is not called.

What am I missing? I have no issues handling other events.

Comment: Show us an example code that exhibits this behavior. Simple WinForms app with two text boxes and a button + `Validating` event works right of the bat.

Comment: Also, check the [Control.Validating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating) event's Remarks section about when that event is raised

Comment: @PawełŁukasik the simple example works as expected. I am also aware of the documentation and when the events are being raised. my question is more if there is anything that could ruin this, that I'm not aware of or that is not mentioned in the documentation.
having a textbox, a connected event handler and the causesvalidation property being true should be enough to make it work but it doesn't work.
this is part of a large application. is there anything that could override the causesvalidation of a child for example?

Comment: calling Validate() works as expected btw so my event handling should be ok

Answer (score 0):

The `AutoValidate` property of the parent UserControl was set to `Systems.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable`

This disables automatic validation on focus change.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autovalidate?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-form-autovalidate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autovalidate?view=windowsdesktop-7.0